# An error occurred while attempting to reach the Sanity API

Tags: reactjs, helper, sanity

It looks like the error is being caused by the current origin (http://localhost:3333) not being allowed for this project. If you are a project administrator or developer, you can head to the project management interface. Add the origin under the CORS Origins section. Do remember to allow credentials!

Comment: I can not build this project using Sanity. There are show many reason.